# How to add sequence for specific values in R

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
 a    b
 1    0
 2    0
 3    0
 4    1
 5    1
 6    1
 7    0
 8    0
 9    0
10    1
11    1
```

Desired dataframe would be

```
 a    b     Flag
 1    0      1
 2    0      2
 3    0      3
 4    1      4
 5    1      4
 6    1      4
 7    0      5
 8    0      6
 9    0      7
10    1      8
11    1      8
```

The sequence should change for 0 and shall remain same for 1.

I am doing it with following command

```
df$flag <- with(a, match(b, unique(b)))
```

But,does not give me desired output.

Comment: Why is flag=4 in the 4th row? b=1.  Also row 10 looks wrong.

Comment: That's the sequence I want to generate.

Comment: Yes.It will only change for first 1

Comment: If the first value of column b is 1, Flag shoud start with 0?

Comment: It will start with 1 and if next row is also 1 then it will have a value 1 and so on. (1,1,0,0,0) Flag will be (1,1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This has been updated to account for the first element of b being 1. Thanks to @tk3 for pointing out that a change was needed.

It looks like your rule is to increase flag if b is zero OR if it is the first 1 in a sequence.

This will give your answer.

```
cumsum(1 + c(df$b[1],diff(df$b)>0) - df$b)
[1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 8
```

If you just wanted to increase flag when b is zero, you could use
`cumsum(1-df$b)`.  Except that would not change the flag for the first one in a series. So I wanted to make an altered version of `b`  that would set b=0 for all of the first ones. You can use `c(df$b[1], diff(df$b) >0)` to get all of the places that b changed from zero to one - the "first ones". Now

```
 df$b - c(df$b[1],diff(df$b)>0)
 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

changes all of the "first ones" to zeros *unless* it is the first element of b. With this altered b we can use cumsum as above. We want to take cumsum of

> 1 - ( df$b - c(df$b[1],diff(df$b)>0) ) = 1 + c(df$b[1],diff(df$b)>0) - df$b

Which was my response

```
cumsum(1 + c(df$b[1],diff(df$b)>0) - df$b)
[1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 8
```

The original version worked only for df$b[1] = 0.  The updated version should also work for df$b[1] = 1.

Comment: This is what I needed,can you please make me understand your code?

Comment: Will add a bit to the answer.

Comment: For b (1, 1, 0, 0, 0) flag is outputting (0, 0, 1, 2, 3). If you can fix this, would be a really nice answer!

Comment: Yes,It should output (1,1,2,3,4)

Comment: Considering Flag is the output of cumsum, maybe just add an if? if(df$b[1] == 1) { Flag <- Flag + 1 }

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do what you want.
I find it a bit complicated but it works.

```
sp <- split(df, cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(df$b)))))
df2 <- lapply(sp, function(DF) {
    DF$Flag <- as.integer(DF$b != 1)
    if(DF$b[1] == 1) DF$Flag[1] <- 1 
    DF
})

rm(sp)    # clean up

df2 <- do.call(rbind, df2)
df2$Flag <- cumsum(df2$Flag)
row.names(df2) <- NULL
df2
#    a b Flag
#1   1 0    1
#2   2 0    2
#3   3 0    3
#4   4 1    4
#5   5 1    4
#6   6 1    4
#7   7 0    5
#8   8 0    6
#9   9 0    7
#10 10 1    8
#11 11 1    8
```